# How do I return the variables in the last line of this OOP Ruby code?

Tags: ruby

```
class Human  # Problem received from Raul Romero
  attr_reader :name 
  
  def initialize(name)
  end
 
end

gilles = Human.new("gilles") 
anna = Human.new("gilles") 

puts anna.equal?(gilles) #should output true # 
puts anna + gilles # should output annagilles
```

How do I make the last line of code output annagilles?

Comment: Hint: You need a `+` method to be able to do the `+` operation.

Comment: @Nnamdi , you just need to create an instance variable for the parameter "name"(@name = name).

Comment: `anna.equal?(gilles) # should output true` – do you expect that output because their `name` values are both `"gilles"`? If so, how is `anna + gilles` supposed to output `annagilles` instead of `gillesgilles`? Is the return value based on the variables names instead of their `name` values? Please clarify. (you can [edit] your question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, there are a couple of things you might need to complete your **Human** class:

```rb
class Human  # Problem received from Raul Romero
  attr_reader :name 
  
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end
```

you need to set the instance variable **@name** in order to read it.

next your `puts anna.equal?(gilles)` check wont work because **.equal?** checks if you are dealing with the same object. likewise `"a".equal("a") #=> false`, so in your case only `anna.equal?(anna)` will return true.

then `puts anna + gilles` shouldnt work because you are trying to add two instances together (not their names). so maybe this would work:

```rb
gilles = Human.new("gilles") 
anna = Human.new("anna") # note that you have 'gilles' here in your example
puts anna.name + gilles.name #=> 'annagilles'
```

so in order to get the value you passed to the initialize (which is then set to **@name**) you need to call that value with **.name**, ie `some_human.name`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was made aware that there is a problem on the line that says "anna = Human.new("gilles")". It should be "anna = Human.new("anna")"

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get a result using `+` then below is the solution

```
class Human  
  attr_reader :name 
  
  def initialize(name)
      @name = name
  end
  
  def +(other)
    name + other.name
  end  
end

gilles = Human.new("gilles") 
anna = Human.new("anna") 

puts anna.equal?(gilles)  
puts anna + gilles
```

Output:

```
false
annagilles
```

but I prefer the below solution

```
class Human  
  attr_reader :name 
  
  def initialize(name)
      @name = name
  end
  
  def +(other)
    Human.new(name + other.name)  
  end
  
  def to_s
    name
  end      
end

gilles = Human.new("gilles") 
anna = Human.new("anna") 

puts anna.equal?(gilles)  
result = anna + gilles 
puts result.to_s
```

Output:

```
false
annagilles
```